# Equipotent sets Cantor-Bernstein-Schroeder

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I try to prove that  # $\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$ $=$  # $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ .

I think that  $\{0,1\}$ $\subset$ $\mathbb{N}$ then $\{0,1\}$ < $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ and exist a injective function.

Can anyone give me some ideas?

Comment: No need to use Cantor-Bernstein-Schroeder here. An explicit bijection is fairly simple to come up with.

Comment: what is your proposal for bijective functions? @MarkSaving

Comment: Start with a function $f \in \{0, 1\}^\mathbb{N}$; that is, a function $f : \mathbb{N} \to \{0, 1\}$. We need to produce some subset $P_f \subseteq \mathbb{N}$. We need to know how to determine whether $n \in P_f$ for each $n$, and we know that either $f(n) = 0$ or $f(n) = 1$. So what are some obvious choices for $P_f$?

Also, there's nothing special about $\mathbb{N}$ here. So if you like, come up with a bijection $\{0, 1\}^A \to \mathcal{P}(A)$ for an arbitrary set $A$.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$ is the set of functions from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\{0,1\}$ and explicitly construct a bijection to $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}),$ the set of subsets of $\mathbb{N}.$

Comment: If I prove that exists a bijection  from N to { 0,1} it is enough? do you have any idea for the function? @subrosar

Comment: @Jason Going from $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ to $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}},$ the bijection takes a subset $X\subseteq \mathbb{N}$ to its characteristic function, a function $f_X$ with $f_X(a)=1$ when $a\in X$ and $f_X(a)=0$ when $a\not\in X.$